# How to make ubuntu realize application type?

Tags: application-development, java, xdg-open

I made a text editor for Ubuntu in Java, and now I want to upload it on the Ubuntu Software Center but I have ran into a problem, how will Ubuntu recognize that my application is an editor once people download my application? is there a way to register my app in Ubuntu with Java as an editor so when people try to open a text file, my application shows in the "open with" menu? any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a .desktop file for your program and install it to `/usr/share/local/applications`. It should then appear in the main menu and in the list provided by the "choose application" dialog. To make it open text files, use the MimeType and Categories lines. For example, the .desktop file for Leafpad includes this:

```
MimeType=text/plain
Categories=GTK;Utility;TextEditor;
```

Comment: More on how .desktop files work: http://linuxcritic.wordpress.com/2010/04/07/anatomy-of-a-desktop-file/